# How can I search for a movie and prefer results with the search term in the title over results with the search term in the description

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I have the following to search for a movie

```
select * from movie where title like ? or cast like ? or director like ? or description like ?  order by votes desc limit 40
```

How can I order by movies that have the search term in the title then votes?

something `like order by termInTile, votes desc limit 40`

```
String resultSql = "select * from movie where title like ? or cast like ? or director like ? or description like ?  order by votes desc limit 40 ";
statment = connect.prepareStatement(resultSql);
statment.setString(1, "%" + term + "%");
statment.setString(2, "%" + term + "%");
statment.setString(3, "%" + term + "%");
rs = statment.executeQuery();

while (rs.next()) {
    if (movies == null) {
        movies = new ArrayList<Movie>();
    }
    movies.add(getMovieFromRs(rs));
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason that `ORDER BY title, votes` won't work, since you've already filtered on the search term...?

Comment: @asteri Yes, he/she wants to give priority to those that have the search term in the title; not to order by the title.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an `order by` clause:

```
select *
from movie
where title like ? or cast like ? or director like ? or description like ? 
order by (title like ?) desc,
         votes desc
limit 40;
```

The `title like ?` will return a boolean, with 1 for true values.  The `desc` will put these first.  Note you will have to include an additional parameter when you call the query.  Or use named parameters, so you can reference a single parameter multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question asked in the title:

```
SELECT *
FROM movie
WHERE title like ? or cast like ? or director like ? or description like ? 
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN title like ? THEN 1 WHEN description like ? THEN 2 ELSE 3 END)
LIMIT 40
;
```